# Detect progress of Async file(s) upload in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to upload my file(s) on server once opened. I have a function in my service and calling that service to upload my file(s). This is my service function.

```
function post(file) {
var file = file;
if (angular.isDefined(file)) {
  return Upload.upload({
    url: filesConfig.uploadFile,
    data: {
      file: file
    }
  }).then(function (response) {         
      return response;
    },
    function (error) {
      return error;
    },
    function (evt) {
      var progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);         
      console.log('progress: ' + progress + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
}


 }
```

In last evt arg function I am getting progress in variable. I am calling this post function from controller like this.

```
 angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileinput')).on('change', function () {
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
  vm.filess.push(this.files[i]);
  fileUpload.post(vm.filess[i]).then(function (response) {  
    console.log(response);  
  });
}
 });
```

Now I want to detect progress of each file in my controller, to show progress bar in UI. How to detect progress?

Comment: 1 - Use a callback that you send as param to `post(file, callback)` and then execute callback on every progress change; or 2 - Use pub/sub to dispatch an event every time the progress changes and then subscribe to this event in your controller; or 3 - use a mediator/manager/service object that keeps reference to this progress and update it on every step and then inject this reference into your controller and play with it; or 4 - update reference for `file` with the progress value such as `file.progress = progress` inside your service - not quite intuitive though

Comment: can you elaborate it with code example?

Answer (score 1):

Quickest and somehow dirtiest solution is below.

**In controller:**

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileinput')).on('change', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var item = {
      file: this.files[i]
    }; 

    vm.filess.push(item);

    fileUpload.post(item).then(function (response) {  
      console.log(response);  
    });
  }
});
```

**In service:**

```
function post(item) {
  var file = item.file;

  if (angular.isDefined(file)) {
    return Upload.upload({
      url: filesConfig.uploadFile,
      data: {
        file: file
      }
    }).then(function (response) {         
        return response;
      },
      function (error) {
        return error;
      },
      function (evt) {
        item.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
      });
  }
}
```

Doing that, you're wrapping your `file` within an item object, keeping `file` as property on that object. In your service, you're directly modifying the reference for your item.

On view, you just need to loop through `vm.filess` and you can access the dynamically property `progress` added.

Is not the best solution, I think that's the quickest I can think of with your setup.